# Accessing Friend of Friends Photos with Facebook GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Does anyone know if there is anyway possible to access a friend of my friends photos with GraphAPI or FQL?

I can't seem to get images of friends of friends. Seems weird that my app can't but the images are displayed on my Facebook wall/posts. The fact that if I login to Facebook in a web browser and I can see the images seems to prove that it isn't really a privacy issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: People seem to misunderstand this regularly … just the fact that a user can see something on facebook.com does _not_ mean the same info has to be available via API. The API restricts access to data in different ways – otherwise automated data mining would be too easy, and neither Facebook nor I as a user would want that.

Comment: Did you want to access their photo albums or just profile picture ? Photo albums like @CBroe said aren't accessible, but profile picture can be got.

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniBhangi . Getting their profile picture would be a billion times better than nothing. Can you please post some information how to do this as an answer?

Comment: Here's the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/) for the same @JeshuaLacock.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using Facebook graph API explorer to get the friends of my friends.My input was

```
     /friendid/friends
```

The API Explorer throws the following exception

```
 {
    "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation",
    "type": "FacebookApiException",
    "code": 100
     }
 }
```

It seems there is no access token available to get the friends of friends..

So It's not possible using Graph Api.